# "Leaving Facebook' warning when a link is clicked

Tags: facebook

In a messenger bot we have, we are sending the users articles from our website they may find interesting and we have received reports that some of the users, when clicking on a link , receive the following warning message:

Leaving Facebook
You followed a link on facebook.com that redirects to another website:
http://finance.walla.co.il/item/2970532
You can now continue to this website or go back to the page that you were on before.
Remember, only follow links from sources that you trust.

Why am I seeing this?
The link that you clicked on was generated for an account which is not currently logged into this browser session. we're showing you this to double check that you intended to go to the link's destination.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87uA2.png)

Searching online, we've found answers suggesting to approach facebook to change the security settings of our website and add it to their trusted sites but we couldn't find a way or an answer as to how to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.fiverr.com/rana_nadeem3041/solve-leaving-facebook-warning 
maybe help you but you will have to pay

Answer (score -1):

You are seeing this because Facebook is either, catching clicks on a elements, or rewriting the src, such way that when clicked, it lands into an interstitial page informing them that they are leaving their domain. Is a security feature for your users.